# Angular set css style for :host in ngOnInit

Tags: angular

I don't know how to set css style for :host {} in ngOnInit in component.
Can use Renderer to set this?

Example:

```
<app-a *ngFor ="let a in alist" [a] = "a"></app-a>
```

In ngOnInit app-a i wanna to set width height style by percent for :host of app-a component when in rendered by ngFor?

Can I do it?

Many Thanks.

Comment: please, provide some code example of your current scenario, as this could be achievable in many ways

Comment: Usually you wouldn't set styles imperatively. Add styles to `@Component({ styles: [...], styleUrls: [...]})`. You can set/remove classes or attributes in `ngOnInit()` to make different parts of your styles apply depending on these classes or attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You usually set styles in a declarative way in the component decorator:

```
@Component({
   styles: [':host { display: block; }']
});
export class AppComponent {}
```

But if you really need to do that from `ngOnInit`, you can insert the host element and use renderer:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private host: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.host.nativeElement, 'display', 'block');
  }
```

Comment: Thank for your help sir :).

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `@HostBinding` decorator like:

```typescript
import { Component, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';  

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: `./app.component.html`
})
export class AppComponent {
  @HostBinding('style.display') display: string;
  @HostBinding('style.width.%') width: number;
  @HostBinding('style.height.px') height: number;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.display = 'block';
    this.width = 50;
    this.height = 500;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help sir :).